# Perl extract range of elements from a hash

Tags: perl, hash

If I have a hash:

```
%hash = ("Dog",1,"Cat",2,"Mouse",3,"Fly",4);
```

How can I extract the first X elements of this hash. For example if I want the first 3 elements, %newhash would contain ("Dog",1,"Cat",2,"Mouse",3).

I'm working with large hashes (~ 8000 keys).

Comment: hash not guarantee elements order, use array or array of hashes, if you need ordered list

Comment: I can sort the hash first can't I?

Comment: you mean to sort it to array ? o'c you can

Comment: @Lebowski156 you can extract sorted lists of keys or values from a hash and you can do it numerically, lexicographically or whateverically. Important is what you *want*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"first X elements of this hash" doesn't mean anything.  First three elements in order by numeric value?

```
my %hash = ( 'Dog' => 1, 'Cat' => 2, 'Mouse' => 3, 'Fly' => 4 );
my @hashkeys = sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys %hash;
splice(@hashkeys, 3);

my %newhash;
@newhash{@hashkeys} = @hash{@hashkeys};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use something like this:

```
my %hash = ("Dog",1,"Cat",2,"Mouse",3,"Fly",4);
for ( (sort keys %hash)[0..2] ) {
    say $hash{$_};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have an array 1st:

```
my %hash = ("Dog" => 1,"Cat"=>2,"Mouse"=>3,"Fly"=>4);
my @array;
foreach $value (sort {$hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} }
           keys %hash)
{
  push(@array,{$value=>$hash{$value}});
}

#get range:
my @part=@array[0..2];
print part of result;
print $part[0]{'Cat'}."\n";
```

Comment: from the sample data, I suspect it should be `<=>`, not `cmp`

Comment: @ysth idk, i just copypasted from [here](http://www.tizag.com/perlT/perlhashes.php) (sorting by value)

Comment: @ikegami `print 3 cmp 2`: 1, `2 cmp 3`: -1 , same with <=> what the difference ?

Comment: @eicto, I told you the order with cmp is 1,10,2,20,... That's very different than 1,2,10,20,...

Comment: ikegami also fixed another bug that you should have noticed if you'd tried your code

Comment: that worked as i answered, may be i pasted code from snipplet, but i really checked it and adopted for situation, http://codepad.org/GuFYwwhZ

Comment: ok agree difference with cmp, have no time to check it right now, but why not just `>=`  in that case?